# Can someone explain what this line of python code does?

Tags: python

```
composite = [True] * 2 + [False] * n
```

I am having a hard time understanding what this python code means. Is it initializing an array? Also if so, is there a specific name for this type of syntax?

Comment: Try it. <padding>

Comment: Not quite , it's initializing a list. A list is a kind of array, but Python has several standard array types - tuple, list, array.array, and then there are the arrays used by the popular 3rd party library, Numpy. So it's a good idea to be specific and use the correct names for these things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It creates a list with 2 True elements and then n False elements. Example:

```
>>> n = 5
>>> composite = [True] * 2 + [False] * n
>>> composite
[True, True, False, False, False, False, False]
```